# Camel netty component: Failed to create selector

Tags: java, sockets, apache-camel, netty, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to use netty to consume bytes out of a tcp socket. I am using Apache Camel 2.12.1, Spring DSL and Windows. My route is pretty simple:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" autoStartup="true">
    <route id="my-route">
        <from uri="netty:tcp://127.0.0.1:4102?sync=true&amp;textline=true" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        <to uri="file:./data" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I am getting this exception when starting the route:

```
2013-11-15 19:33:23,749 ERROR [Thread-5] - org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1344) ~[camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:120) ~[camel-spring-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:301) ~[camel-spring-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [?:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:95) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.<init>(NioServerBoss.java:49) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:55) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:26) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioBossPool.init(AbstractNioBossPool.java:65) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.<init>(NioServerBossPool.java:40) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyServerBossPoolBuilder.build(NettyServerBossPoolBuilder.java:65) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.startServerBootstrap(SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:132) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.doStart(SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:93) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    ... 100 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.open()Ljava/nio/channels/Selector;
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(AbstractNioSelector.java:335) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.<init>(AbstractNioSelector.java:95) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.<init>(NioServerBoss.java:49) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:55) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.newBoss(NioServerBossPool.java:26) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioBossPool.init(AbstractNioBossPool.java:65) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBossPool.<init>(NioServerBossPool.java:40) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.NettyServerBossPoolBuilder.build(NettyServerBossPoolBuilder.java:65) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.startServerBootstrap(SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:132) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.netty.SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.doStart(SingleTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:93) ~[camel-netty-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
    ... 20 more
```

Any ideas with it is not starting? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` is usually caused by having an incompatible jar (too old or too new) on the `CLASSPATH`.

(I have occassionally found the free JBoss Tattletale useful for identifying old *duplicate* copies of classes or jars hanging around on my `CLASSPATH`. However, duplication may not be the problem here.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it relates to  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.open()Ljava/nio/channels/Selector;

Comment: Yes, it does. NoSuchMethodError is always caused by an incompatible jar. If you don't believe me, Google it.

Comment: I found the issue. Camel Zookeeper and Camel Netty were including different versions of the netty library and it seems there are changes in the api and Camel was looking for a method that wasn't there at all. So, finally it was a incompatible jar

Comment: I will check if we can let the camel-zookeeper and camel-netty using the same version of netty.

Comment: I just filled a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7032  in camel and applied the patch for it.